# Combining lists in a matrix

Tags: matrix

So I have a list of data `A={1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,6.1}` etc and `B={2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9}`
I need to combine the lists into a matrix C

```
{{1.1,2.5},{1.2,2.6},{1.3,2.7},{1.4,2.8},{6.1,2.9}}
```

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: c=Transpose[{A, B}]

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is a duplicate. Here is a small selection of ways (inclusive of Algohi's):

```
Thread[{A, B}]
Transpose[{A, B}]
Inner[List, A, B, List]
MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {A, B}]
```

Algohi's is efficient.